# SuperLearner for survival outcome in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I recently started reading about the **SuperLearner** and I am trying to run **SuperLearner** for survival outcome in R. I found an example code in the [*Targeted Learning*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-9782-1) book by Mark J. van der Laan and Sherri Rose, which require the data to be converted to long format to run.

The function that converts the data to the long format is no longer available. Here is the code:

```
library(survival)
data(lung)
subLung <- subset(lung, select = c(time, status, age,ph.ecog, ph.karno, pat.karno))
subLung$female <- (lung$sex - 1)
subLung <- subLung[complete.cases(subLung), ]

## Expand subLung to Long Format
longData <- SuperLearner:::createDiscrete(time =subLung$time, 
event = (subLung$status == 2),dataX = subset(subLung, 
select =-c(time, status)), n.delta = 30)
```

The `createDiscrete` function is no longer available in the **SuperLearner** package. Is there any other function that will convert the data to long format? If not, then a toy example of how to convert the data into appropriate long format would be very helpful. Or a sample **R** code to run **SuperLearner** for survival outcome would be also helpful.

Comment: You could try `gather` from the `tidyverse` package: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html. Now also known as `pivot_longer`

Comment: @p0bs: thanks for the suggestion. I guess **SuperLearner** require a special conversion, different from the usual long format that we use for the longitudinal outcome. The `n.delta` argument above splits the time to 30 intervals and does something, which I am not sure about.

Comment: Do you have a sample R code to run SuperLearner for survival outcome? I am also trying to understand the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. To run **SuperLearner** for survival outcome, the data structure has to be converted to counting process format, meaning that, the *time* variable should be split in such a way that at most 1 event can happen given a time interval. The `survsplit` function in **survival** package does that! Thanks to Dr. Eric C. Polley.